# Center UIButton to Superview class programmatically (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I'm trying to center button in the view within a UIStackView subclass.

```
//  ButtonsController.swift
//  player

@IBDesignable class ButtonsController: UIStackView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupControls()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupControls()
    }

    private func setupControls(){
        //Buttons variables
        let playButton = UIButton()
        playButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        addArrangedSubview(playButton)
}
```

In the Storyboard I've create Horizontal Stack View and set it to custom class ButtonsController. I want Play button to be centered within that view, that's why I use "self.centerXAnchor" as reference to Superview.

But simulator crash with an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
>   (NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x60800026c680 "UIButton:0x7feba5d112f0.centerX")
>   and (NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x60800026c700
>   "player.ButtonsController:0x7feba5c0e390.centerX") because they have
>   no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference
>   items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

How I actually can reference to Superview within that class?

Comment: Do not set constraints. Simply `addArrangedSubview`. If the layout does not fit your needs, change the properties of the `UIStackView`, as it handles the layout of its subviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is, you are trying to add a constraint (which references other views) before adding your view as subview. You should add it as subview first, then create constraints. That will get rid of the crash.

```
addArrangedSubview(playButton)
playButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Also, I don't know what you are trying to achieve here, why you are using a UIStackView as container. Bu that constraint will probably cause trouble for you. You are adding your UIButton as "arranged subview", which means its constraints will be created automatically. You can activate some constraints like width if you configured your UIStackView accordingly (its distribution propery etc.). But centerX is problematic on a horizontal stack view. You can try centering your stack view inside its superview or instead of adding your uibutton as arrangedsubview, adding it as subview:

```
addSubview(playButton)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem! I will also definitely consider your second advice.